# SQL Server - How to convert Comma separated list with quotes to one simple column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have an external app sending queries in a comma separated list, but this list is already divided not just by commas but with simple quotes, so I have been unable to assign the value to one variable as `varchar(max)`.

If I do a select, I get 1 row with as many columns as comma separated fields.

```
select 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q'
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----
a    b    c    d    e    f    g    h    i    j    k    l    m    n    o    p    q

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Instead of 1 row with that many columns, I need 1 column with many rows.

I have tried with `CROSS APPLY` but since I do not know the name of the columns it is not working. Also tried `CONTAINSTABLE` and `FREETEXTTABLE` but haven't been able to make them work as I need.

What I need is:

```
items
-----
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
...
```

Comment: What do you want the column to look like?   abcde or a,b,c,d,e?

Comment: just edited the question to add what I am looking for, a table with only 1 column and multiple rows, kind of what *CROSS APPLY* or *UNPIVOT* does

Comment: i think you should do in on Front end or insert it into some table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you prefer not to use a function like Ken's suggestion, you can try something like the following:

```
declare @list varchar(500)
declare @tbl table (mychar varchar(10))
declare @next int

set @list = '''a'',''b'',''c'',''d'',''e'',''f'',''g'',''h'',''i'',''j'',''k'',''l'',''m'',''n'',''o'',''p'',''q'''

set @next = CHARINDEX(',', @list)

while (@next>0)
begin

INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(REPLACE(REPLACE(LEFT(@list, @next), '''', ''), ',', ''))    --remove quotes and comma

set @list = RIGHT(@list, len(@list)-@next)

set @next = CHARINDEX(',', @list)

end

INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(REPLACE(REPLACE(@list, '''', ''), ',', '')) --insert one last token

select * from @tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

We have a handy Split String function laying around that I'm sure originated on stack somewhere.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_split_string](@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))        
returns @temptable TABLE (val varchar(8000))        
as        
begin        
    declare @idx int        
    declare @slice varchar(8000)        

    select @idx = 1        
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return        

    while @idx!= 0        
    begin        
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)        
        if @idx!=0        
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)        
        else        
            set @slice = @String        

        if(len(@slice)>0)   
            insert into @temptable(val) values(@slice)        

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)        
        if len(@String) = 0 break        
    end    
return        
end;
```

usage is

```
SELECT * from fn_split_string('a,b,c', ',')

val
___
a
b
c
```

Comment: yeap, but the problem is that what I get from the App is not 'a,b,c', but 'a','b','c'
    SELECT * from fn_split_string('a','b','c', ',')
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'a'.

The problem is that I am unable to sent 'a','b','c' as one single string, the function recognizes that as multiple parameters

Comment: fn_split_string(Replace('a,b,c', '''', ''), ',')

Comment: Seems the app should be cleansing that data for you with some sort of string replace before sending it to the database. If not, hopefully you're at least receiving a variable containing the string 'a','b','c' that can you parse before trying to work with it.